# How do I dynamically update the JFrame with new data instead of a button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I have a Jframe with 5 buttons. One of the buttons allow the user to add products to the inventory. The other buttons won't work until the user has added something to the inventory. Once the user has added something to the inventory, the user has to update the Jcombobox by the pressing the buy button and running some code that adds the data from an arrayList to the Jcombobox. My question is, I how do skip all of that and have it update right after the user adds an item to the inventory(This what I mean by dynamically).

relevant Code

code from Machine Frame that gets the information from an arraylist to a string array and adds it to the combobox.

```
case "buy":
            if(product.checkInventory())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainMenu, "No Products in the vending machine.");   
            }
            else
            {
                productList.removeItem("Product");
                String tempArray[] = product.sendingInformationToVendor();

                for (String tempArray1 : tempArray) 
                {
                    productList.addItem(tempArray1);
                }
            }
```

code from the addProductFrame that adds to the arrayList in the class productInventory

```
case "enter":
                if (productDescription.getText().equals("") || costField.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(addProductFrame, "Filling in all the necessary fields.");
                } else {
                    String prodName = productDescription.getText();
                    String tempProdCost = costField.getText();
                    double prodCost = Double.parseDouble(tempProdCost);
                    int q = (int) quantity.getValue();

                    Product p = new Product(prodName, prodCost, q);
                    proInv.addProduct(p);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(addProductFrame, "This product has been successfully added to the vending machine");
                    productDescription.setText("");
                    costField.setText("");
                    quantity.setValue(1);
                }
```

Each of these snippets of code are in a class called processAction that implements actionlistener and each of the string next to the keyword case is the action command for each button

Comment: object.repaint();, so perform the update to the frame/textfield/whatever, then call repaint()

Comment: No, @Petro's advice is incorrect as repaint shouldn't be needed. You need to add an object to the JComboBox's model, and doing this will update the combobox. A call to repaint is never needed in this situation. The specific solution will depend on your code.

Comment: Well there's certain situations when you need to manually do it. I don't think he's trying to do what your suggesting, as he did say "how do skip all of that" . I may be wrong, I guess we'll see.

Comment: @Petro: again, `repaint()` is **never** required to display new information added to a JComboBox. Never.

Comment: Well his question was for the JFRAME not the combo box. I assumed he was trying to update more than just the box....

Comment: @Deathslice: clarify your question, show pertinent code please.

Comment: Well, then the obvious solution is to put the code that updates the JComboBox in the ActionListener of the first JButton. If you need more specific help, you'll need to fill in more details and show code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Ok I should have clarify that only thing that should update is the combobox because that is where the user can where all the new products are

Comment: What you will need is some way for the routines which add products to raise some kind of notification that the rest of the system can register to and react to...

Comment: I've added some of my code for you to look at.

Comment: I've tried alot of stuff and nothing has been working so far. I need help